# Lanzar evento en el form desde un control de usuario

Tags: c#, windows-forms, usercontrol

Tengo un formulario que va a contener varias copias de un control de usuario, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando dentro de uno de esos controles de usuario se haga click en un boton, se lanze un evento del formulario que lo contiene.

He pensado en guardar una referencia del formulario en el constructor del control de usuario y asi poder llamar a cualquier metodo de ese formulario, pero me parece una solucion poco elegante.

Agradeceria si alguien me puede indicar alguna manera mas elegante de hacer esto.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien. Tu lanzas el evento desde el control de usuario, y en el formulario recibes ese evento. Uno de los parámetros del evento es el sender, o sea, que control es el que ha enviado el evento. Si eso no te sirve,puedes mandar un parámetro en el evento que identifique que control lo mandó.

Comment: @Pikoh Buenas, si tengo un formulario con N controles de usuario, cuando dentro de ese control de usario se pulse un boton, se debe añadir un nuevo control de usuario en el formulario en el que estan. Los controles se van añadiendo de manera dinamica. Lo que no consigo es referenciar el formulario desde el control, me gustaria hacerlo de manera elegante para poder usar ese concepto en otros proyectos futuros.

Comment: Es que eso es lo que te digo. El control no tiene porque saber absolutamente nada del formulario principal. El lanza un evento y dice "me han pulsado este boton". Es el formulario el que debe estar escuchando este evento, identificar que control es en el que se ha pulsado el boton y actuar en consecuencia (creando otro control o lo que sea)

Comment: @Pikoh, gracias, y abusando un poco de tu ayuda, si tengo un control de usuario, dentro de otro control de usuario, ¿se haria de la misma manera?, porque en este caso en un control de segundo nivel de profundidad ya pierde la referencia del parent form.

Comment: En ese caso, yo iría "escalando" hacia arriba el evento. Es decir,el control de segundo nivel lanza un evento que recibe el control de primer nivel, y este se encarga de "relanzarlo" para que llegue al principal.

Comment: Aqui tienes un ejemplo de lo que te decía [What is the preferred way to bubble events?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4349195/579895)

Comment: @pikoh muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacerlo por propagación de eventos:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {

        public delegate void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e);
        public event ButtonClick OnButtonClick;
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            button1.Click += new EventHandler((sender, args) =>
            {
                OnButtonClick?.Invoke(this, null);
            });
        }
    }



public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            UserControl1 usrCtrl = new UserControl1();
            usrCtrl.OnButtonClick += UsrCtrl_OnButtonClick;
            this.Controls.Add(usrCtrl);
        }

        private void UsrCtrl_OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click en boton dentro del usercontrol");
        }
    }
```